# Process Stopped But Give No Error in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, error-handling

I have compiled my project in vb 2010, then i have proccess that loop some proccess to save, delete, update database, but it stopped and give no error information,

when i check to my database, it is not what i want to, not all data saved.

how can i trace this?

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger to see where it stops or fails to save the data to the database.

Comment: i want to, but i handled thousand data to process

Comment: Log the database calls to a file - then you can examine the log file to get a better idea of where it's failing.  Alternatively, you can post the code and maybe someone can point out some likely areas where it might fail.

Comment: nah! can you give me a sample code for make log file, Tim?

Comment: Sorry - I don't have the time.  It's pretty trivial - just a matter of writing to a text file.  A quick Google search should give you lots of examples.